# Creating a second child window causes the first to disappear?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, msdn

I'm attempting to create both "Button" style and "Edit" style windows, so that the user can enter a string and then press the button to proceed through the application.

The button is created first:

```
hButton = CreateWindow(L"button",L"Label",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,100,100,
             100,100,hWnd,(HMENU)BUTTON_ID,NULL,NULL);
ShowWindow(hButton,SW_SHOW);
```

Then, later in the application, I repaint the window, so I redisplay the button ...

```
ShowWindow(hButton,SW_SHOW);
```

... and then create the text box:

```
HWND hTextBox = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,TEXT("Edit"),TEXT(""),
                WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE, 500,500,500,500,hWnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);

HFONT font =CreateFont((int)24.0f,0,0,0,FW_THIN,false,false,false,
              ANSI_CHARSET,OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
              CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,DEFAULT_QUALITY,FF_DONTCARE,L"Helvetica");
SendMessage(hTextBox,WM_SETFONT,(WPARAM)font,false);
ShowWindow(hTextBox,SW_SHOW);
```

Unfortunately the button never re-appears, and the text box doesn't look right (no CLIENTEDGE style, no Helvetica font, etc.) Interestingly, if I remove the text box code, the button shows up just fine after the second ShowWindow(hButton,SW_SHOW) call.

Any ideas on what my problem could be? Since both the button and the text box are child windows of hWnd, could they somehow be "interfering"?

Comment: Little to go by.  Why are you calling ShowWindow when the button is already WS_VISIBLE?  When does it actually get hidden?  Why are you using such strange window position and sizes?

Comment: The button disappears when I repaint the window, but shows back up with the second call to ShowWindow. I don't know why my positions and sizes are "strange", but I only put them like that to simplify code, because they contain variable expressions in my actual code.

Comment: A button should never disappear when you repaint a window.  Maybe you forgot WS_CLIPCHILDREN.

Comment: WS_CLIPCHILDREN did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Well, I'm a little closer. The window isn't displayed but a white rectangle is shown where it should be. So clearly WS_CLIPCHILDREN worked, since the area isn't painted ... but the window isn't displayed. I even called IsWindowVisible, which said that it was, but I don't see it. Any ideas?